# Save order of fields in Django Modelformset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to save the order of fields in a formset, but I want the order field hidden (i.e. so the user can't edit it).

The documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/formsets/#adding-additional-fields-to-a-formset) says I can override the add_fields method to redefine the attributes of the order field.  Here is my overridden class:

```
class MyBaseFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(MyBaseFormSet, self).add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields['order'] = forms.HiddenInput()
```

And the from views.py:

```
    MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ModelA,
                                      ModelB,
                                      formset = MyBaseFormSet,
                                      can_order = True)
```

The relevant part of my template file:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
<tr>
{% for form in formset %}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}{{ hidden }}{% endfor %}
    <td>{% for visible in form.visible_fields %}{{ visible }}{% endfor %}</td>
</tr>
```

It raises a TemplateSyntaxError when rendering the page: `Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'HiddenInput' object has no attribute 'label'`  I suspect my overridden class is not correct, but the documentation isn't helping me much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some digging in django.forms.models and copied this out of it.  This is how I solved it:

```
    form.fields['ORDER'] = forms.IntegerField(label=(u'Order'), initial=index+1, required=False)
    form.fields['ORDER'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Answer (score 2):

[`HiddenInput` is a widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#hiddeninput), not a form field, so try:

```
form.fields['order'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

Comment: Using this solution, I had to change ['order'] to ['ORDER'] and it renders on the page correctly.  However, in my form.cleaned_data, ORDER is None.  How would I grab the actual number from the page?

Comment: better yet, change `'order'` to `forms.formsets.ORDERING_FIELD_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this (using your example):

```
MyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    ModelA,
    ModelB,
    formset=MyBaseFormSet,
    can_order=True,
    widgets={forms.formsets.ORDERING_FIELD_NAME: forms.HiddenInput()},
)
```

However, this overrides any `Meta.widget` setting contained within a form if you use the `form` argument to `inlineformset_factory`.  Also, the order field is added later to the form so adding an entry to `Meta.widget` for the ordering field does nothing.  So, if using the `form` argument then what's already been suggested here seems to be the best:

```
class MyBaseFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(MyBaseFormSet, self).add_fields(form, index)
        try:
            form.fields[forms.formsets.ORDERING_FIELD_NAME].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        except KeyError:
            pass
```